# how to mention path interface in Mockito.any()

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

in my main class code.

**Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\test\", "a.txt");
testClass.init(filePath);**

while writing case i mock testClass
**Mockito.doNothing().when(testClass).init(Mockitio.any());**---> its not working because because path is interface

if I pass real value init test case fail in jenkin build and also i dont want to upload the file in my branch.

is that any pass Path interface in Mockitio.any()

Comment: I dont't think that Path is the problem, I can match a  path with Mockito.any() easily.
Please show more code and the error/exception ...

Comment: If you're mocking the testClass (and not spying), why do you even need to do this at all?